# Measuring API response times during testing (Jest and Chai)

Tags: api, testing, jestjs, chai

I have a graphQL API which I'm end-2-end testing with Jest and Chai:

```
  it("Query works", async () => {
    const res = await chai
      .request(app)
      .post("/api")
      .send({
        query: `
           {
            someQuery {
              data
            }
          }
        `,
      });

    expect(res.body.data.someQuery.length).toBe(31);
  })
```

The API is requesting live data from a seeded Postgres database created within Github actions so that the tests are as close to real life as possible.

Since I've tried to replicate a real-life scenario with the setup, I was hoping I would also be able to record response times for each query while testing, but I can't find a whole lot of information about doing this anywhere.

I don't think chai exposes any information related to how long the query took to execute, so how would I go about extrapolating this information? Is there a third library I should be using to keep track of this information specifically?

Comment: What do you mean by "record" Do you want to send that data somewhere? Or do you just want to fail the test is the request takes to long?

Comment: I just want access to it so I can save into an external file. A JSON, or a plaintext one. So really as long as I can assign it to a variable it's probably good enough.